# npm Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs' at Error (native)

Tags: node.js, npm

I have recently installed nodejs (version 6.2.1) and nodejs tools for visual studio (version 1.1.1) on my laptop. I have cloned one of my projects from GitHub, when I try to update my npm dependencies (i.e. Express, Bower) I get this error

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs'
              at Error (native)
```

My default nodejs install is at C:\Program Files\nodejs.

I have also tried to run the command npm update using admin permission in cmd, all this does is create the folder but the command seems to never finish.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help

Comment: Did you include your `node_modules` directory as part of your repo?  If so, do you have the same version of npm as when you created the repo that you uploaded to GitHub?

Comment: node_modules is not included the repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It occured to me the same error but another situation.You just need to open the Node.js command prompt as Administratior.I hope this can help you.